# onApprove route gives an error after successful CREATE route

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to capture the order via onApprove route but getting the following error:

`Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`
[image]

**The purchase has been successfully** but the process is not complete and I am not forwarded to the URL which I mentioned in php CREATE method. My onApprove route is looks like below (not putting all the codes to make it clear):

```
  paypal.Buttons({
            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('https://example.com/TESTS.php?create=testing', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.result.id;
                });
            },
            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('https://example.com/TESTS.php?id=' + data.orderID, {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
```

As you see looks normal as I am able to create the order without any problem. But once I pay in the popup page error is seen. And following is my php file for CREATE/CAPTURE:

```
    <?php  
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest;
    
    require __DIR__ . '/Checkout-PHP-SDK-develop/vendor/autoload.php';
    $clientId = "AQgUM4x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd";
    $clientSecret = "EDm88hmcFd6arhd5vaJ6v9AWjIvCScR6E6s0eM3OKqwf1uZt0G0KlLNUXG057vesyXR4eYP3RKDLJBz8";
    
    $environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    $client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);
    
   if(isset($_GET['create']) && $_GET['create'] == 'testing'){
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = [
                         "intent" => "CAPTURE",
                         "purchase_units" => [[
                             "reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
                             "amount" => [
                                 "value" => "100.00",
                                 "currency_code" => "USD"
                             ]
                         ]],
                         "application_context" => [
                              "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancelled",
                              "return_url" => "https://example.com/success"
                         ] 
                     ];
    try {
         $response = $client->execute($request);
         echo json_encode($response);
         
    }catch (HttpException $ex) {
       echo json_encode($ex->statusCode);
       echo json_encode($ex->getMessage());
    }
    }

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($_GET['id']);
$request->prefer('return=representation');
try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    echo json_encode($response);
   // return $response1;
     // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
  // return $request1;
}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo json_encode($ex->statusCode);
   // print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
}
```

Tried almost everything but it seems there is something that I don't know about it. Maybe you could see where I am doing a mistake and help me.

The output of `console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));` is in below :

```
"statusCode": 201,
  "result": {
    "id": "19X58570EP734922G",
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "purchase_units": [
      {
        "reference_id": "test_ref_id1",
        "amount": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": "100.00"
        },
        "payee": {
          "email_address": "sb-qlquy8262061@business.example.com",
          "merchant_id": "BHUEK7UQX3KFU"
        },
        "soft_descriptor": "PAYPAL *TEST STORE",
        "shipping": {
          "name": {
            "full_name": "John Doe"
          },
          "address": {
            "address_line_1": "Free Trade Zone",
            "admin_area_2": "Bali",
            "admin_area_1": "AZ_zip = 994",
            "postal_code": "994",
            "country_code": "AZ"
          }
        },
        "payments": {
          "captures": [
            {
              "id": "9796275092029330N",
              "status": "PENDING",
              "status_details": {
                "reason": "PENDING_REVIEW"
              },
              "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "100.00"
              },
              "final_capture": true,
              "seller_protection": {
                "status": "NOT_ELIGIBLE"
              },
              "links": [
                {
                  "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/9796275092029330N",
                  "rel": "self",
                  "method": "GET"
                },
                {
                  "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/9796275092029330N/refund",
                  "rel": "refund",
                  "method": "POST"
                },
                {
                  "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/19X58570EP734922G",
                  "rel": "up",
                  "method": "GET"
                }
              ],
              "create_time": "2022-03-25T22:28:23Z",
              "update_time": "2022-03-25T22:28:23Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "payer": {
      "name": {
        "given_name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
      },
      "email_address": "sb-qtxuk6283362@personal.example.com",
      "payer_id": "J4RS8Q76ZEKZ2",
      "address": {
        "country_code": "AZ"
      }
    },
    "create_time": "2022-03-25T22:28:12Z",
    "update_time": "2022-03-25T22:28:23Z",
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/19X58570EP734922G",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    ]
  },
  "headers": {
    "": "",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": "1496",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Date": "Fri, 25 Mar 2022 22",
    "Application_id": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
    "Caller_acct_num": "BHUEK7UQX3KFU",
    "Paypal-Debug-Id": "92f6c8280dfc2",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return fetch('https://deals.az/TESTS.php?id=' + data.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id,

This line makes no sense. You want `+ data.orderID`

`.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id` is something you would later reference from a capture *response*.

See the demo code at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Okay, as always you saved me and now  the purchasing is successfully completed but with error. I think the process is not completed fully even though the amount in PayPal was sent. I am not forwarded to the page which I mentioned and I am getting an error in console which I have added in my first post. what variable could be undefined can't figure out.

Comment: The reason of this error is  this line : `var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];` which makes attempt to call 0 index of array. I don't know why this happens , I actually do know almost nothing in JS but if you remove this line then you will get the flow working without any error.

Comment: That would imply there is no successful transaction, for some reason. The sample already does `console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));`, so it's simple to look at the browser console and see exactly what the response is.

Comment: `console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));` this shows me the output in console tab of browser. So, it means I am getting every detail of the purchase process from CAPTURE method which comes from `PHP`. I would say that the structure might be not appropriate but if that would be the reason then it should have broken in the half way of the second part of the workflow (CAPTURE process I mean).

Comment: And what does it show, exactly? The status of the capture will be in there.

Comment: The output has been added to my first post in above. Please have a look.

Comment: It says PENDING_REVIEW. DO you have payment review enabled for the sandbox business account? See https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts , find the acount, "...", 'Settings' tab.  That in itself shouldn't cause `var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];` to be undefined, though, since it is there in the orderData you logged.

Comment: I have turned the review payment option off, it was on though. Now it shows me as `completed`. But the error still there as you mentioned. That is very interesting, I mean how it could be possible if I am getting orderData ? I am stuck  actually and can't get an id or the order..

Comment: On your server, change `echo json_encode($response);` to `echo json_encode($response.result);` or similar. Only send back the response body, not extra keys like "statusCode" and "result" that are from how PHP encapsulates the HTTP response, and of no interest to the client-side JS.

Comment: Yes, you are right encapsulation was hindering the process. I have changed it like you said and erased the status code and etc. so it sends pure json output without extra data. It works like expected. without any error. Thank you very much! It should be great example for anyone else who has difficulties.